# Oracle hierarchial queries

Tags: connect-by, oracle-apps, grouping-sets

I am trying to pull out all the hierarchy values for a particular segment in Oracle Apps(referring tables `applsys.fnd_flex_Value_norm_hierarchy` & `applsys.fnd_flex_values`). I want a tree like display starting from the top parent and going down until the last descendant) something like this:

[image: screenshot1]

I have been able to pull the data with repeated parents across each lines and currently formatting this manually in excel, but am sure there is a way to do this using `sql` itself but not able to do it. Please note I have already written a `sql` which gives me data as follows.

[image: screenshot2]

Any suggestions would be really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

We have a treewalk SQL for this data in our Blitz Report library here: https://www.enginatics.com/reports/fnd-flex-value-hierarchy/

The output looks like this:
https://www.enginatics.com/example/fnd-flex-value-hierarchy/